# Create an AWS lambda function to shut down instances based on low CPUUtilisation

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So I have already got as far as the below, I am trying to make the lambda function apply to a specific VPC (all instances within that VPC). There is a costed way of doing it within AWS but getting customers to pay the extra $2.20 per instance for detailed monitoring is beyond difficult to justify. Based on what I've read so far it is ridiculously easy to write the function per instance, again it can be done almost by clicking next next finish within AWS, but we don't want to have to define the individual instances based on how our clients grow so rapidly.

```
import boto3


def put_cpu_alarm(instance_id): 
    cloudWatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch') 
    cloudWatch.put_metric_alarm( 
    AlarmName = f'CPU_ALARM_{instance_id}'
    AlarmDescription = 'Alarm when server CPU does not exceed 10%'
    AlarmActions = ['arn:aws:automate:eu-west-1:ec2:stop'] 
    MetricName = 'CPUUtilization'
    Namespace = 'AWS/EC2' 
    Statistic = 'Average'
    Dimensions = [{'Name': 'InstanceId', 'Value': instance_id}]
    Period = 300
    EvaluationPeriods = 12
    Threshold = 10
    ComparisonOperator = 'LessThanOrEqualToThreshold'
    TreatMissingData = 'notBreaching' 
    )

def lambda_handler(event, context): 
    instance_id = event['detail']['instance-id'] 
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2') 
    instance = ec2.Instance(instance_id)  
    if instance.instance_type.endswith('xlarge'): put_cpu_alarm(instance_id)
```

I was hoping the small if statement in the last line could possibly be updated to run against the specific VPC, but haven't had much look finding the correct line to reference a single VPC, or security group that may help.

Any advice massively appreciated.

Comment: Could you please update your question to explain the general flow? For example, what triggers the Lambda function? Is your intention to create one alarm per instance in the VPC? Will the alarms be deleted when an instance is terminated, or is that irrelevant for this question?

Comment: The lambda function will be triggered by Cloudwatch alarms, also defined within the code, period of 300 (5 mins), over 12 eval periods (total of 60 mins).

The intention is for a single workflow type scenario, hence I haven't just done the simple one you can do within the GUI per instance - I want this to apply no matter how many instances get added to the VPC / customer envrionment).

Instances wont be terminated, they will simply be shut down ready for students to then power back up when they next need them.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your requirement is to check all Amazon EC2 instances within a given VPC every *n* minutes for low CPU usage. If it falls below a given threshold, such instances should be stopped.

First, please note that CPU Utilization might not be a good measure of "usage". You mention students, which suggests there might be a lot of interactive command-line work, which does not use much CPU. You will need to experiment to find a good 'trigger' that indicates non-usage.

Rather than creating individual Amazon CloudWatch alarms, I would recommend:

- Create an **Amazon CloudWatch Events rule** that triggers an AWS Lambda function every *n* minutes
- The Lambda function will:

  - Call `DescribeInstances()` to **obtain a list of EC2 instances** (either filtering down to the VPC within the API call, or filtering after the response is received)
  - For each instance, if the instance is Running, **obtain CloudWatch Metrics CPU Utilization** for the instance (which is captured by default every 5 minutes) for the desired time period (eg for the last 15 minutes)
  - If the instance is below the desired threshold, call EC2 to **Stop the instance**

This method will automatically handle any instance in the VPC without having to create/delete alarms specific to each instance.